# Error while passing argument list to Superclass

Tags: ruby

Sorry if the question is unclear as I'm new to Ruby.
I have a Parent class (not implemented by me) **Reports** that has a method **query** defined as:

```
class Reports

      def self.query(id:, is_active: false, is_timestamp: false, version: DEFAULT_VERSION, limit: DEFAULT_LIMIT)
    
         <<code>>
end
```

I have defined a child class **Report** that inherits **Reports** and defined the same method **query** as below:

```
class Report < Reports

    def self.q_version(id)
           <<some logic to decide version>>
    end
    def self.query(id:, is_active: false, is_timestamp: false, limit: DEFAULT_LIMIT)
        version = q_version(id)
        super(id, is_active, is_timestamp, version, limit)
    end
```

Now when I run the code, I'm getting an argument error as such:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 0; required keyword: id)
```

I suspect I'm not doing the super call correctly but couldn't figure out which part.

so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method's signature tells that it expects keyword arguments like this:

```
def self.query(id:, is_active: false, is_timestamp: false, limit: DEFAULT_LIMIT)
  version = q_version(id)
    
  super(id: id, is_active: is_active, is_timestamp: is_timestamp, version: version, limit: limit)
end
```

Or you could use the [new shorthand hash syntax](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14579) when you are on Ruby 3.1+:

```
def self.query(id:, is_active: false, is_timestamp: false, limit: DEFAULT_LIMIT)
  version = q_version(id)
    
  super(id:, is_active:, is_timestamp:, version:, limit:)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! changing all keyword arguments as below worked:
`super(id: id, is_active: is_active, is_timestamp: is_timestamp, version: version, limit: limit)`